# Mac vs Linux (for cycle acts different)

Tags: bash, mac, copy-paste

I need your help in an extraordinary question. I have the following line in my bash script.

```
for f in $(find ./ -name '*.pdf' -or -name '*.indd' -or -name '*.indb'); do cp "$f" ./Cleaned; done
```

As you can see, it scans the current folder for PDF, INDD and INDB files and it copies them to the folder called Cleaned.

Now, I'm working on Fedora 25 Workstation and the scripts works just fine. On Fedora 22+ it all works. 
On Mac OS X 10.9.5 it does the same thing.

The problem is: There is one PDF file that was generated by Adobe InDesign and in one page, one particular word is messed up after the copy.

The works looks like: Másnapos
How it looks after the copy: Másnap??
If I select the work and copy it to a TXT file, it looks like: ??????os (so the oposite)

I've figured out, if I copy the file on the Mac with just simply cp file location, then it all goes well. If I scan the folder and copy them like that, then only this file has this minor issue.

Please notice the word is still in the PDF elsewhere, and there it is fine.

Oh, and on other MAC with the same version, it works.... what the f....ork?

So my question: How can a simple copy in a for cycle mess up a PDF file, but only at one word and only once in the whole document on some MAC OS X, but not on any Fedora and CentOS version?

Comment: I was hopeing that even MAC users come around to SE. It could be that on some linux distributions also acts the same since it is a bash script what we are talking about. It is not strictly MAC specific, it is more like Bash specific in my thinking, but as you wish. I just hope somebody knows something about this or at least can tell me what to pay attention for.

Comment: This sounds like a freak accident to me. `cp` is supposed to make a byte-by-byte copy, regardless of operating system or program it is invoked from. Is this behaviour consistent/reproducible?

Comment: In other news, you could tidy up that script by just doing everything in a `find` one-liner: `find . -iname "*.pdf" -or -iname "*.indd" -or -iname "*.indb" -exec cp {} Cleaned/ \;` Use of `iname` will also ensure you'll catch files with a `.PDF` extension, not just a `.pdf` (same for the other two extensions). With that you don't need the unnecessary loop you're currently using.

Comment: Siguza: yes, it is. 4 MACs are doing it.

Comment: Have you verified that the word is correct *before* the copy?  Can you post screenshots?